# Within a simple finite state machine, Error : 'int' object is not iteratable

Tags: python, int, fsm

Im trying to create a finite state machine that reads in the states, transitions, and the strings. I am trying to create it without objects. Everything works up till my for loops. However, as soon as the loop begins I get the error message:

```
line 42, in <module>
    for I in len (Strings):
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Why is this happening? Any tips would be appreciated.

```
Sfile = open("states.txt","r")
States = []

ReadLine = Sfile.readline()
while ReadLine != "":
    A, B, C = ReadLine.split(",")
    States.append((A, bool(int(B)), bool(int(C))))
    ReadLine = Sfile.readline()
print States, "\n"
Sfile.close()



Tfile = open("transistions.txt","r")
Transitions = []

ReadLine = Tfile.readline()
while ReadLine != "":
    ReadLine = ReadLine.rstrip()
    Tran4, Tran5, Tran6 = ReadLine.split(",")
    Transitions.append((Tran4, Tran5, Tran6))
    ReadLine = Tfile.readline()
print Transitions
Tfile.close()

Strfile = open("strings2.txt","r")
Strings = []

ReadLine = Strfile.readline()
while ReadLine != "":
    Readline = ReadLine.rstrip()
    Strings.append(Readline)
    ReadLine = Strfile.readline()

print Strings, '\n'
Strfile.close()


for I in len (Strings):
       for C in Strings[I]:
           Start = '0'
           Current = Start
           if C in Strings == '0':
                Current = A
           else:
                Current = State

print Current...
```

My different text files contain:

- states.txt

State2,1,0
State3,0,1
State4,1,0

- transitions.txt

State1,0,State2
State2,1,State3
State3,0,State4

- strings2.txt

10100101
1001
10010

Comment: `len(Strings)` is going to return an integer - the length of Strings. Did you mean `for i in Strings` perhaps?

Comment: `for I in len (Strings):` --> `for I in range(len (Strings)):`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't iterate over an integer. I think you meant to iterate over a `range` object `range(len(Strings))`. This will work because the `range` object is an iterable and the `int` is not.

Answer (score 1):

You want `i in range(len(Strings))`. Len returns a whole number, like 13 -- `in` wants something like a vector. `range(13)` gives you a vector `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]`.

Quiz question: why is the last number 12?

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to iterate over an integer, it should be

```
for I in range(len(Strings))
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to turn the number to a string as you cant pick out the first digit of an int. So str(1234)='1234'  '1234'[0]='1'

Answer (score 0):

`len(s)` gives you an integer, and you can't iterate over that. If you want to iterate over a collection of strings, use `for s in strings`.

Answer (score 0):

you can't iterate over a number or any other singular object, you need a composite object like a list, to do that. In this case look like you want this

```
for words in Strings:
    for C in words:
        ...
```